# How to find special file in the entire solution by Roslyn?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am coding specific rule by [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) .

In this rule, the analyzer is parsing method declaration and its references in entire solution by `SymbolFinder`.

One of my requirements is finding a way to understand a Solution [has multiple projects] is either Asp.Net Webform or Asp.MVC by Roslyn.

Based on our projects,for this purpose, I need to find a file which is called "Web.SiteMap" in entire solution,

if this file exists, I can understand this project is Webform type otherwise is MVC.

I am wandering how can I do it by Roslyn in c#?

Comment: Can't you better determine that by looking at the assembly references of the project?

Comment: How can I check  Sysyem.Web.MVC  assembly  in the solution ?

Comment: You can't. One solution can contain WinForms, WebForms and MVC projects.